# ClientStart.Connected method doesn't work with wifi

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a software that get some data from a server via Tcp. This is how i handle the reconnection:

```
        Dim ClientPlaylist As New TcpClient()

        While (Not ClientStart.Connected)


        Try

            ClientPlaylist.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipPlaylist), CInt(portPlaylist))
            
            Console.WriteLine("TCP Client Connection established.")
            Console.WriteLine(New String("-", 40))

            StreamPlaylist = ClientPlaylist.GetStream()
            
            ReceiveData()

            Dim wP As New BinaryWriter(StreamPlaylist)
            
            wP.Write(magicNumber)
            wP.Write(dataLenPStr)
            wP.Write(dataPlaylist)

        Catch Err As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect!")
            lbConnection.BackColor = Color.Red
            lbConnection.Text = "CONNECTION LOST"
            lbConnection.Invalidate()
            lbConnection.Update()
            lbConnection.Refresh()
            Me.Update()

            Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
            sw.Start()
            Do Until sw.Elapsed.Seconds = 5
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop
            sw.Stop()
        End Try
    End While
```

This works perfectly when i lost connection in a wired LAN (unplugging the ethernet cable to simulate it). Labels and all the stuff in the try catch statement works. When i try it with wifi looks like the exception isn't thrown or i don't go into the while loop (labels and console don't show nothing) but the reconnection works.

Comment: Erk, don't wait 5 seconds by battering DoEvents a billion times! `Await Task.Delay(5000)` or something

Comment: Is this some existing server you're connecting to, or did you write the server too? There are easier ways than this if you wrote the server...

Comment: @CaiusJard is a pre existing server

Comment: Never ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate.